# Scraping Dynamic Web Pages (ASPX)

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler

I want to scrape all of match details played in Turkish Super League.
The data is here: http://www.mackolik.com/Standings/Default.aspx?sId=3170

Click on "Fikstür" and then select "Hafta".
Fikstür means Fixture and Hafta means week in Turkish.

In this page, each weeks have matchIDs when you hover on the score.Ie, when you select Hafta=1 and the match id of "Genclerbirliği-Adaletspor" is 342212.

So, first job is collecting all match ids.
When i want to get these id completely, i inspected all of elements. One month ago, i can get match ids from www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/FixtureHandler.aspx?command=getMatches&id=3170&week=11  which can be get by Network.

But when i get into there, i get a message "403 Forbidden error". But all ids were here. How can i get these match ids or deal with the problem?

I'm using Python.

Comment: @alecxe i tried 4 times. I changed my ip several times, but i get still this error. There must be a code which prevent me to reach the ids.

Comment: Most likely, it's just that you need to provide a User-Agent header. But, make sure you don't violate the Terms of Use and stay on the legal side.

Comment: So, headless browser?

Answer (score 1):

i found my solution:

```
import mechanize
from lxml import html as lh
import requests

br = mechanize.Browser()
page=br.open("http://www.mackolik.com/Standings/Default.aspx?sId=3170")
head=page.info().headers
response = requests.get('http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/FixtureHandler.aspx?command=getMatches&id=3170&week=1', headers=head)
response.text
```